# Python pandas custom unmelt - create columns from duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, melt

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

base_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,2,3],
    'base_value': [100, None, 123.1]
})

id  base_value
1   100.0
2   NaN
3   123.1
```

There's also another one:

```
extended_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'ext_id': [100, 500, 90, 1, 1000],
    'role_1': [True, False, False, True, True],
    'role_2': [False, True, True, False, False],
    'ext_value': [10, 5, 21, 200, 500]
})

id  ext_id  role_1  role_2  ext_value
1   100     True    False   10
1   500     False   True    5
2   90      False   True    21
2   1       True    False   200
3   1000    True    False   10
```

I would like to get the following dataframe as a result:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,2,3],
    'base_value': [100, None, 123.1],
    'ext_value_role_1': [10, 200, 500],
    'ext_value_role_2' :[5, 21, None]
})

id  base_value  ext_value_role_1    ext_value_role_2
1   100.0       10                  5.0
2   NaN         200                 21.0
3   123.1       500                 NaN
```

The logic behind the transformation is as follows. For each row in `base_df` find matches in `extended_df`. The resulting dataframe will contain as many additional columns (excluding `id`, `base_value`) as there are `role_*` columns times number of `ext_value` columns in `extended_df`. If `id`'s role is set to `False` the resulting value in column is `None`.

I've come up with the code posted below. It works for the small example but I'm hoping to get something more `pandas`esque.

```
def multiply_by_boolean(boolean_value, variable):
    if boolean_value is False:
        return None
    elif boolean_value is None:
        raise ValueError('boolean_value cannot be None')
    return variable

extended_df['ext_value_role_1'] = extended_df.apply(lambda x: multiply_by_boolean(x['role_1'], x['ext_value']), axis=1)
extended_df['ext_value_role_2'] = extended_df.apply(lambda x: multiply_by_boolean(x['role_2'], x['ext_value']), axis=1)

res_df = extended_df[['id', 'ext_value_role_1', 'ext_value_role_2']]

res_df = res_df.groupby('id').agg('max')

res_df = res_df.merge(right=base_df, left_index=True, right_on='id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `merge` to build a temporary dataframe and then just add the relevant columns:

tmp =base_df.merge(extended_df, on='id')

```
resul_df = base_df.set_index('id')

for role in ['role_1', 'role_2']:
    resul_df['ext_value_' + role] = tmp.loc[
        tmp[role] == True, ['id', 'ext_value']].set_index('id')

resul_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

It gives as expected:

```
   id  base_value  ext_value_role_1  ext_value_role_2
0   1       100.0                10               5.0
1   2         NaN               200              21.0
2   3       123.1               500               NaN
```